# Is it allowed to return a non-literal type from a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

```
struct Outer
{
    explicit constexpr Outer(int ii) : n(ii) {}
    explicit constexpr Outer(double dd) : n(dd) {}

    explicit constexpr Outer(double*) : Outer(3.1415926) {}
    explicit constexpr Outer(int*): Outer(42) {}

    template <typename R>
    static
    constexpr
    Outer meow(R* r = nullptr) { return Outer(r); }

    int    as_i() const { return n.i; }
    double as_d() const { return n.d; }

    union Inner
    {
        int i;
        double d;

        constexpr Inner(int ii) : i(ii) {}
        constexpr Inner(double dd) : d(dd) {}
        ~Inner () {}; // non-trivial destructor

    };

    Inner n;
};

//#include <type_traits>
//static_assert(std::is_literal_type_v<Outer>); // failed by both GCC and clang

int main(int argc, char**)
{
    auto const o = Outer::meow(&argc);
    return o.as_i();
}
```

The above code is compiled by GCC 12.1 but rejected by clang 14.0.0

https://godbolt.org/z/o6Tvrrdsv

clang (correctly, in my opinion) complains that

```
<source>:12:11: error: constexpr function's return type 'Outer' is not a literal type
    Outer meow(R* r = nullptr) { return Outer(r); }
          ^
<source>:28:11: note: 'Outer' is not literal because it has data member 'n' of non-literal type 'Outer::Inner'
    Inner n;
          ^
<source>:36:24: error: no matching function for call to 'meow'
    auto const o = Outer::meow(&argc);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:12:11: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with R = int]
    Outer meow(R* r = nullptr) { return Outer(r); }
          ^
```

Even though `o` is merely const, not `constexpr`, shouldn't this be an error? `meow` is trying to do something which shouoldn't be allowed.

(If I make `o` into `constexpr`, then GCC complains that `Outer` has a non-trivial destructor.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the return type of a `constexpr` function must be a literal type and `Outer` is not. If a *function* definition doesn't satisfy the `constexpr` requirements, the program would be ill-formed.

However, you have a function *template* here. `constexpr` on a function template is allowed as long as there is at least one specialization which satisfies the requirements of a `constexpr` function. However, if this requirement is not fulfilled, the program isn't *ill-formed*. It is *ill-formed, no diagnostic required* (IFNDR).

There is no specialization here satisfying the requirements because you always have the `Outer` return type and so the program is IFNDR.

Both compilers are correct. They do not need to diagnose that the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Ah, the dreaded IFNDR :(